# Why is a disabled SWT link not grayed out?

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I disable `org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Hyperlink` control just calling `hyperLink.setEnabled(false)`.

However after that the link doesn't looks like disabled control. The link is not grayed out (but I can't click it of course).

The question is: why the link is not grayed out and what should I do to gray out disabled links?

Answer (score 0):

did you try setting gray foreground explicitly ?

you can use following helper method:

```java
public static void setEnabled(Link link, boolean enable){
    if(link.isEnabled()!=enable){
        if(enable)
          link.setForeground(null); // resets to system's default color
        else
          link.setForeground(link.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
        link.setEnabled(enable);
    }
}
```

Comment: just tried. this works. but now I need to set color back, and how can  I obtain the default color for hyperlinks? :) I don't want to ask control to return it's foregraound color and store it - it would be to complicated solution for such a thing that we supposed to have for free.

Probably I can say Eclipse somehow to use "gray" as foreground for disabled hyperlinks?

Comment: this looks good, but doesn't work for me. In my eclipse the default color for enabled links is "dark blue", and "light blue" when you hover over. But if I set foreground to "null" then links become black and "light blue" when you hover over.

Answer (score 0):

Just extend Hyperlink and set the default colors.  Alternatively you could create a composite delegate and forward the interface if it isn't too big - that's probably preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, in addition to [Santosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104018/santhosh-kumar-t)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2346365/6309), with [Eclipse 4.3 M6](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.3M6-201303141330/news/), you can restore the default color more easily, since you now have:

> A new constant (SWT_COLOR_LINK_FOREGROUND) has been added that will return the native color of hyperlinks on all platforms.

[image: SWT link color]